# Shortcut to write few lines of code - visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, beamer

I am writing a few slides in beamer/latex in VS code.

Is there a way I can create a combination of keys that will automatically write a few lines of code?

E.g. when I press `Ctrl+Shift+Q` or any combination of keys I want to write the following lines of code:

```
\begin{frame}{}
\begin{itemize}
 \item placeholder
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand that. I think that's javascript right?

Comment: you write a simple part JSON data structure